# Array of shader storage buffers

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have been successfully using shader storage buffers of the following form (OpenGL 4.3 Core):

```
layout(std430) buffer Data
{
  uint data[];
};

...

uint x = data[i];
```

Now I am trying the following:

```
layout(std430) buffer Data
{
  uint data[];
} buffer_data[2];

...

uint x = buffer_data[0].data[i];
```

but this refuses to link, reporting:

> error C1308: no size for unsized array

for the line accessing the buffer (Note that this is reported during linking, not compilation). Is this a fault on my part, a limitation of the GL specification or a driver bug? If this is a limitation, is there a suitable workaround?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I was under the impression that SSBs behaved like pointers to allocated buffers, and that having an array like my example would be just an array of two pointers, and work as an alternative to having two named buffers (which works fine).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I misread the `buffer` declaration. You have a single dynamic-length array at the end of your SSB this does not require link-time knowledge of the size of `data`. Out of curiosity, if you replace the non-constant expression used to index `data[]` in the second attempt, does it change anything? (e.g. `uint x = buffer[0].data[0];`)

Comment: My gut tells me this is a driver bug. There is a general requirement that unsized arrays be indexed using constant integral expressions, but that was relaxed when SSBs were introduced (for the last element in the storage block ***only***)... the linker may be confused.

Comment: It also really does not help that you are using the name `buffer` for your buffer. I would seriously consider a better name that does not collide with a reserved keyword. Any number of weird things can happen if you make a practice out of this. The compiler should actually be generating an entirely different kind of error for doing this.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman That is true. That does generate an error. My simplified example was too simplified. I'll change the name. (My actual code does not use this name).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman (Re. using a constant expression instead of `i`): No, that does not make a difference.

Comment: For reference, I am using NVidia GeForce driver 332.21.

Comment: Since this is not your actual shader code, is there any chance you could post a complete shader that produces this problem in its entirety? I can only assume that the line `uint x = buffer_dat[0].data[i];` is in fact the one generating **C1308** because that is the only line of code you included.